# Error 1146 while updating the column which has foreign key to table of another db in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am using two database `db1` and `db2`.

t2 table of `db2` is having a foreign key to `t1` of `db1`.

When i am updating the same column, mysql is giving me error message `table db2.t1 doesn't exist`.

Comment: And where is yor update statement?

Comment: Show your update statement?

Comment: update db2.t2 set column='value';